# $.post data naming issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello i did a jquery ajax post that calls for a php form depending on the key : the key is get by the `data-app`here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form1').keyup(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        var key = $(this).data('app');
        $.post('page2.php', { key : value }, function(data){
            $("div[ data-show='" + key + "' ]").text(data); 
        });
    });
});
```

the problem is that where i specify the data value `key` instead of giving me the value `data` i want it names it as key, is there a way i can make the variable work? so that the `key` is equal to the `data` value, and not equal to `key`, because in the php it works if i do this `$_POST['key'];` but lets say `data-app="username"` then `key` will be equal to `username` and the php will read like this: `$_POST['username'];` hope is understandable and thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form1').keyup(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        var key = $(this).data('app');
        var obj = {};
        obj[key] = value;
        $.post('page2.php', obj, function(data){
            $("div[ data-show='" + key + "' ]").text(data); 
        });
    });
});
```